Paradox involving probability that a triangle is acute in circles and spheres
For a set of points $s$, let $P_s=$ probability that three undependent uniformly random points chosen from $s$ are the vertices of an acute triangle.
We have:

$P_\text{circle}=\frac14$
$P_\text{disk}=\frac{4}{\pi^2}-\frac18\approx0.280$
$P_\text{sphere}=\frac12$
$P_\text{ball}=\frac{33}{70}\approx0.471$

(References: circle, disk, sphere, ball)
In two dimensions, the probability for the boundary (circle) is smaller than the probability for the interior (disk).
In three dimensions, the probability for the boundary (sphere) is larger than the probability for the interior (ball).

Is there an intuitive explanation for this discrepancy?

This question was inspired by another question: "What is the maximum probability that three random points, chosen from some set of points in 3D space, are the vertices of an acute triangle?"

I'd consider how the sample space changes from disk to ball as opposed to how it changes from circle to sphere. The "size" of one seems to grow much more than the other. Maybe how the proportions change is related to this somehow. This is just my first instinct though, I'm not exactly sure if it's actually the best approach or not.

What happens in higher dimensions? There is a general heuristic principle that in high dimensions, most of the volume of a ball is near the boundary. Maybe that principle is in play here.
